# How do I move from the desktop directory to my home directory?

Tags: command-line

Yesterday I was working with the terminal where i install the most programs and packages, but I needed to change the directory to desktop(myusername@hostname-desktop:~$) and I did good,but now i want to change back to(myusername@hostname:~$)

I can't put it like it was before,because now its in desktop directory and cant do nothing personal to the system.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ubuntu.

To change directories, use cd

```
cd
```

If you do not put in an argument you will go to your home directory. You can also

```
cd ..
```

go up one directory.

See - http://linuxcommand.org/

You may not get all the way through that site, but the initial information is invaluable.

Comment: +1 for linuxcommand.org, that's a very nice introduction to the command line (and basic bash scripting).

Answer (score 0):

Using `cd ~` will cd to your home directory.